# Sorcery redirects wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorcery

User wants to sign up at domain.com/users/new, however the user accidentally presses "enter" and all fields are filled in blank.
Now comes the problem. I have two options. If I remove...

```
...else
redirect_to new_user_path
end
```

the user will automatically be redirected to domain.com/users (after filling the fields in blank) and where the sign up field errors will nicely be displayed above the form.

However if I add that code above instead of removing it, the user will be redirected to the same link - that means /users/new and unfortunately the user will not have his form errors displayed nicely, they will actually not be displayed at all. 
How come that the errors show up at domain.com/users and not at domain.com/users/new?

Comment: what is your `config.cookie_domain` set to in sorcery.rb?